# How to overcome error from a single javascript while enabling others in HTMLUnit?

Tags: web-scraping, htmlunit

I am new to HTMLUnit. I am trying to get information from a public site (given in the code below). While I can open this public url in Chrome browser or Chrome Selenium extension without error and continue functioning with it, my HTMLUnit program is throwing an error as below which it seems is stemming from a particular Javascript in the page. My question is, how to resolve this kind of problem ? I cannot disable the javascript altogether as the form section with details will not be available in that case. However if I use the command

EcmaError: lineNumber=[55] column=[0] lineSource=[] name=[TypeError] sourceName=[https://www.marutisuzuki.com/js/server_cookies.js] message=[TypeError: Cannot find function fetchServerCookie in object [object Object]. (https://www.marutisuzuki.com/js/server_cookies.js#55)]
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot find function fetchServerCookie in object [object Object]. (https://www.marutisuzuki.com/js/server_cookies.js#55)

```
        String pageAsXml = null;
        String pageAsText = null;   
         try{
             
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME); 
            HtmlPage page = 
            webClient.getPage("https://www.marutisuzuki.com/dealer-showrooms/");
            //webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
            pageAsXml = page.asXml();
            pageAsText = page.asNormalizedText();
            System.out.println(pageAsText);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
webClient.getOptions.setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
```

For more have a look at https://htmlunit.sourceforge.io/javascript-howto.html.

BTW: this is an error in the page itself because you got the same in real browsers.
[image]

Comment: While your solution is somewhat not working always, it gave me insight into the HTMLUnit coding. I have now included HTMLUnit src into my project and tweaking necessary parts for my need. Thanks for the suggestion when I was thinking it to be end of the road for this project. And yes, I checked the Chrome error console, thanks for that too. Gave me confidence.

Comment: If you have any suggestions pull requests are always welcome.